# javascript coockie

Tags: javascript

i need to know how javascript pass through  semicolon in coockies. when I give file name with semicolon(eg ;.txt) along with some other value like folder id, document type, and size and try to store all these  in cooockies using document.coockie in javascript.

since in javascript coockiename and value separated using semicolon coockie store values where it found semicolon.If filename contain semicolon it doesnt store it

How can i do it in javascript. and read the value...

Comment: just curious: which filesystem does allow semicolon as part of a filename?

Comment: i have never laughed so hard for so long at the consistent misspelling of a word

Comment: The strategy you need here is called "Escaping" , which means to replace characters that have a special meaning with some'escape sequence' and decode the escape sequence back to the escaped character when reading.

Comment: can we please roll back the edits? pretty please?

Comment: @BertNase A good number, I'd imagine. [ext2/3/4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) allows all but NUL and slash (`/`) in a file-name. NTFS will also happily accept a semicolon (`;`). These are just two off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `escape` the string you want to store in the cookie

eg: `escape('a;')` will give "a%3B"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend encoding the value you are putting into the cookie so that the value you are storing can contain semi-colons.

You may want to look at `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent`.

An example

```
window.encodeURIComponent(';'); // results in %3B
```